# Delimiting double quotes for replacing XML characters

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, escaping, export-to-excel

I am using a template Excel Export class which I found on CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31516/Export-DataSet-to-Multiple-Excel-Sheets?fid=1532097&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx)

and within the class there is a method for replacing certain characters to make them safe for Excel, however the following line seems to be tripping up the system, since it is removing the delimited \" quote and replacing it with a single double quote.

```
 input = input.Replace("\"", """);
```

If I delimit this again, to:

```
input = input.Replace("\"", "\"");
```

it defeats the purpose of the replacement, and if I leave it as it is, the rest of the class trips up because it is an unclosed string. Has anyone come across this before or got any ideas to get around this?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: The triple-double-quote example won't even compile - can you clarify what you are replacing?

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace "\\\"" with "\"" ?

Comment: Well the method is needed to remove the \" escape from XML which is implemented and appended to the string writer at an earlier stage, The \'s need to then be removed before the file is downloaded otherwise Excel's XML parsing will trip up.. I will try your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you don't just use this article's code. It looks like it's not being shown correctly (I suspect it should be `Replace("\"", "&quot;")`, but even if it *were* correct, it wouldn't be good code.

Instead, use an XML API - LINQ to XML is very easy to use. That way you don't need to do any of the XML escaping yourself.

You should almost *never* create XML documents by treating them as simple text. Instead, *always* use an XML API, which is a much cleaner way of making sure you end up creating valid XML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, since I have a feeling that there are quite a few more issues in the XML on there than just the quote escaping...

Comment: @StephenLeake: Exactly. That's the problem with trying to do XML with simple string operations - there are all kinds of things that can go wrong if you're not careful. Always use an XML API.